# How do I handle errors while creating connection on azure storage

Tags: python, azure, connection, azure-blob-storage

Handle the error while making a connection, below code is not working, tried with incorrect names and password still not giving any error

```
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name = account_name,account_key  = account_key)
try:
 if block_blob_service:
    print('connection successful!')
 except Exception as e:
        print('Please make sure the account name and key are correct.', e)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following line of code:

```
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name = account_name,account_key  = account_key)
```

is actually creating an instance of `BlockBlobService` (not sure if creating instance is the correct term :), coming from .Net world) and nothing else.

In order to check if the account name/account key combination is correct, you will actually need to perform an operation on that storage account as there is no `Login` kind of operation supported in Azure Storage.

Normally the way I do it is try to list blob containers from that storage account. When listing blob containers, just set the `num_results` parameter to 1 as we are only interested in checking the account name/key validity and nothing else.

There are three possible outcomes:

1. **Account name/key is correct**: In this case you would not get any errors.
2. **Account name is incorrect**: In this case you will get `remote name could not be resolved` error.
3. **Account key is incorrect**: In this case you will get a 403 error back from the service.

Using these outcomes you can decide whether or not account name/key combination is valid.